# How do I center HTML objects on an MVC 4.0 Web API using Razor application?

Tags: html, css

Okay, bear with me because I'm new to WEB development.

I have an MVC 4.0 Web API application using Razor and Entity Framework 5 (C#).

One of my links takes me to a page which displays data from the EF.

I added an HTML button to this page called "Export to Excel."

I want to center this button on the screen, above the report results.

What is the correct approach for this and how do I do it? I need to understand the PROPER architecture for files and code.

1. Do I use CSS? If so, where do I store the file in the solution? How do I use it on my page?
2. Do I do something specific to Razor?

Should I simply use HTML tags like

Again, all I want to do is center a button on the web page.

Can someone help me with a step by step process to do this correctly?

I'm just having a hard time figuring out where to put code and files (basically how to structure the application properly).

Comment: ASP.NET MVC comes with ready to use project templates, just create one and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CSS`.

```
.centerAlign {
   text-align: center;
}
```

In your view you can then apply the `centerAlign` class to the button:

```
<button class='centerAlign' />
```

You can also make a custom `HTML Helper` that will automatically apply the class for you.

```
namespace YourApplication.Helpers
{
     public static class ButtonExtensions
     {
          public static string ButtonCenter(this HtmlHelper helper, string value)
          {
               return String.Format("<button class='centerAlign'> {0} </button>", value);
          }
     }
}
```

Then in your view you could do:

```
@Html.ButtonCenter("Click me");
```

Comment: I created a CSS file (lets name it Styles). and I put .centerAlign {
   text-align: center;
} in it. Then I went to my view and added: <div class="centerAlign">
    <input id="btnExportToExcel" type="button" value="Export to Excel" />
</div>. it's not centering the button on the screen.

Comment: @Rj - you need to reference the CSS file in your view.  You can drag the `CSS` file from the Solution Explorer window into the View directly and Visual Studio will add the reference for you.

Answer (score 1):

I know there is an answer, but this is a really common way to center objects `margin: 0 auto`.  Since the answer by itself doesn't really explain, I'll provide some detail.

When you build your *View* it is marked as a *.cshtml* file.  Your *View* will contain a series of *HTML* or *Hyper Text Markup Language*.  What you are doing is utilizing a particular *Element* called a `div`.  These are used to help build a structure or layout for your site.

```
<div id="Origin">
     <div class="origin-container">
           <div class="header-style">
                <div id="Origin-Header">
                    <div class="header-container">

                        // Inside Header Elements
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

So essentially this is a *Site Structure*.  You'll notice that I have a tendency to inner-wrap a lot of my *Elements*.  That is because it makes it easier to customize and style my layout, making it more customizable.

If your thinking "How is it more customizable?"  Your partially correct, this *HTML* is simply a structure- The customization will come from your *Stylesheet, Cascading Stylesheet* to be exact.

Your *HTML* will call this *Stylesheet* to help adapt your layout to give a consistent appearance.  So if you'd like to center your header you would put in your stylesheet:

```
#Origin-Header {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

What the command is stating is three things:

- **Margin:** These are the page margins.
- **0:** Is the pixel difference for *Top and Bottom*.
- **Auto:** The left and right pixels.

So rather then a *top, bottom, left, and right* they are all merged together in the short-hand.  You'll have a lot of additional control to your layout as well through your stylesheet.  Bare in mind that this is manipulating those `div tags`. If your trying to align a particular object, it would work identical but rather then focus on the element- You would point it to your *html object*.

But I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is good practice, but the only way I have been able to center entire controls like a button in HTML was to do something like

```
.btn{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
 }
```

I have been able to center the control by setting the button's class to "btn" and using the above css.  The text-align property has never really worked for me in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[i guess is this what you are looking for]
check LIVE DEMO on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samuelbigas/u4C28/)

HTML

```
<section class="iHaveBorder">
    <h3>Help me here!...Center stuff...</h3>
    <div class="myWorderfullDiv iAmRed">
        your report here...
    </div>
    <center>
        <button>DoIt</button>
    </center>
</section>
<h1>::::::OR:::::</h1>
<section class="iHaveBorder">
    <h3>Help me here!...Center stuff...</h3>
    <div class="myWorderfullDiv iAmBlue">your report here...</div>
    <div style="text-align: center;" >
        <button>DoIt</button>
    </div>
</section>
<h1>::::::OR relative:::::</h1>
<section class="iHaveBorder iFeetIn">
    <h3>Help me here!...Center stuff...</h3>
    <div class="myWorderfullDiv iAmGreen">your report here...</div>
    <div class="iWant2BeCenter">
        <button>DoIt</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.myWorderfullDiv{
height: 80px; width: 200px; 
}
.iAmBlue{background-color: blue}
.iAmRed{background-color: red}
.iAmGreen{background-color: green}

.iHaveBorder{border:2px black solid;}

.iFeetIn{display: inline-block;}
.iWant2BeCenter{text-align: center;}
```

check LIVE DEMO on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samuelbigas/u4C28/)